# show wrong answer in multiple selection in SwiftUI

Tags: algorithm, swiftui

When a wrong option is selected, I want to show the wrong option in red and then the correct option in green automatically. But I couldn't do the algorithm for it. How can I do that ? I prepared a sample project about the structure I use. I couldn't show the correct option and the wrong option at the same time when only the wrong option was selected.

[image]

**Model**

```
struct QuestionContainer: Codable, Hashable {
    var questions: [Question]?
}

struct Section: Codable, Hashable {
    var a, b, c, d: String
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case a = "A"
       case b = "B"
       case c = "C"
       case d = "D"
    }
}

struct Question: Codable, Hashable {
    var number: Int?
    var question: String?
    var sections: Section?
    var price: Int?
    var correct: String?
}
```

**QuestionView**

```
struct QuestionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var questionViewModel: QuestionViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(questionViewModel.question.questions?[0].question ?? "empty")
            SectionView(sectionViewModel: SectionViewModel(section: questionViewModel.question.questions?[0].sections?.a ?? "empty", correct: questionViewModel.question.questions?[0].correct ?? "empty"))
            SectionView(sectionViewModel: SectionViewModel(section: questionViewModel.question.questions?[0].sections?.b ?? "empty", correct: questionViewModel.question.questions?[0].correct ?? "empty"))
            SectionView(sectionViewModel: SectionViewModel(section: questionViewModel.question.questions?[0].sections?.c ?? "empty", correct: questionViewModel.question.questions?[0].correct ?? "empty"))
            SectionView(sectionViewModel: SectionViewModel(section: questionViewModel.question.questions?[0].sections?.d ?? "empty", correct: questionViewModel.question.questions?[0].correct ?? "empty"))
        }
    }
}
```

**QuestionViewModel**

```
class QuestionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var question: QuestionContainer = QuestionContainer()
    
    init() {
        getQuestions()
    }
    
    func getQuestions() {
        question = QuestionContainer(questions: [Question(number: 1, question: "What is the chemical formula for water ?", sections: Section(a: "CO2", b: "H2O", c: "C2H6O", d: "H2N"), price: 5, correct: "H2O")])
    }
}
```

**SectionView**

```
struct SectionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sectionViewModel: SectionViewModel
    @State var color: UIColor = .gray
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            
            sectionViewModel.selected = sectionViewModel.section
            color = sectionViewModel.prepareResultColor()
            print("correct: \(sectionViewModel.correct)")
            print("selected: \(sectionViewModel.selected)")
        }) {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color(color), lineWidth: 2)
                    .frame(width: 340, height: 50)
                
                HStack {
                    Text(sectionViewModel.section)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.gray))
                            .bold()
                        
                    Spacer()
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.orange))
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(Color(UIColor.orange).opacity(0.4), lineWidth: 2)
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 12, height: 12)
                            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.vertical, 12)
                .frame(width: 340)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SectionViewModel**

```
class SectionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var section: String = ""
    @Published var correct: String = ""
    @Published var selected: String = ""
    init(section: String, correct: String) {
        self.section = section
        self.correct = correct
    }
    
    func prepareResultColor() -> UIColor {
        if correct == selected && selected != "" {
            return .green
        } else if correct != selected && selected != "" {
            return .red
        } else {
            return .gray
        }
    }
}
```